# Map put not working Java

Tags: hashmap, put, json, linkedhashmap

I have a Map with some values, and I need to put a new entry into it, the problem is that the put "lost" the Object, and I have only the new Key into it.

Here is the code

```
public void addSeries(SerieInterface serieObject)
{
    Map<String, Object> series = this.getSeries();
    if (series == null)
        series = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    series.put(serieObject.getSerie_instance(), serieObject);
    this.setSeries(series);
}
```

"series" is the existent map (is a BasicDBObject, it extendes LinkedHashMap) and I need to add in it the serieObject object (an Object with two String field that extends JSONObject); 
after the "put" command, I have the old two Object in the map and the new with only the "key" 
(i have only {"Key" : { } } )
(I have checked serieObject in debug, it have all the fields)

Any suggestion of the cause? Why the Object "Value" of the Map is lost?
I have not any type of Exception from it, I only lost the value...

Thanks for the help, sorry for my not-perfect English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luca, please describe more clearly what you have in your structure at the end of your test, `{"Key" : { } }` doesn't mean much, what kind of Object is the {} value?

Looking at this `series.put(serieObject.getSerie_instance(), serieObject);` serieObject seems to have at least that weirdly named getSerie_instance key and it's not null.

Also, a few other things:

1) this.getSeries() , if this Map is a class property use that directly, don't use setter/getter if you only return the value.

2) if (series == null), why not initialize this Map in the constructor of the class? It's cleaner this way.

Comment: At the end of the method, in the structure series i have 3 elements.
1 - "ID1" : { "serie_instance" : "ID1" ; "study_instance" : "IDS_1" }
2 - "ID2" : { "serie_instance" : "ID2" ; "study_instance" : "IDS_1" }
3 - "ID3" : { }
When the first two elements are old elements, the third element has the key of "serieObject" that I add but not the value (it has to be like the other two, with "serie_istance" : "ID3" and "study_instance" is the same of the other two)

Comment: Remove the get/set and init the series map in the constructor, the problem could not be here but in another method, are you sure you are not overwriting series or pointing at different things in different places?

Comment: Run it in eclipse and put a breakpoint at this.setSeries(series) and when it stops (don't click next) check the value of series. You just used serie_instance to as the element key, the object cannot be... empty. And please don't use this javascript syntax :D

Comment: SerieObject must have serie_instance and study_instance, if one of them is null i don't call this method, that's because I expect that the new element is not null.
In the debug, i have checked the value of "series" and it is exactly how it must to be, the problem is after the "put".
Sorry for the syntax, it is JSON XD

Comment: Debug it with Eclipse as described, and if the Class is not too big add it in your answer. Im my opinion the issue is elsewhere. Map.put works.

Comment: Wait... what do you do with serieObject after you call addSeries?

Comment: Unfortunally the class is very big, 529 lines...
Is full of getter/setter and it has 3 constructors.
After I call addSeries i do not use more serieObject, i want only that serieObject is stored in the map

Comment: No no, I have no other thread in this project, I can't find a logical explain for this problem...

Comment: By the way, if you do a put, the new element with both key+value must be in the map, and if you don't change serieObject outside of addSeries the value must be still the same that when you put it in. Add a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and after the put and look at the value of serieObject, is still the same?

Comment: Also, what is the value of the new element (in java syntax) ?? null? serie_instance and study_instance, both java.lang.String and equals to ""?

Comment: I'm sure it's just a simple mistake, here you are even using strings as key and that's maybe the simplest way to use Maps.

Comment: The fields of the serieObject are serie_instance and study_instance, and they are two String. The values are "ID3" and "IDS1" respectively.
The value of the serieObject is still the same, before and after the put.

Comment: And in the Map just after the put? There should be an entries array, check that. You should find serieObj there.. you just added it.

Comment: Yes, in the Map there is an Array with 3 entries, the problem is that the third have only the key but not the value (the serieObject).
The other two are pre-esistent, and have both key and value

Comment: Wait... not the value means? value is null or something else?

Comment: Maybe I've found the problem, the old values are SerieObject instance, but the new is a BasicDBObject...

Comment: It's better if you put only 1 kind of object or objects with a common ancestor in these data structures (Map,List,...), but you declared <String,Object> it should work anyway, and you don't have type cast(don't use it as an SerieInterface). By the way... you haven't replied yet about what you mean with with "no value", in Java it could mean null object or uninitialized object...

Comment: Ah sorry, when I said "no value" I mean that empty {} in JSON (I need to send that map on MongoDB).
I have founded that the "values" of the entry are different, maybe is that the cause of the problem, I need to do some experiments, thank you for the help, sorry for the waste of your time. :)